# How do I capture flagstrap select values in a form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Flagstrap, a jQuery plugin for displaying a country selector with flags via Bootstrap's select and button dropdown components.
Thanks to a clear demo page, it was easy getting it to display correctly, but the demo didn't submit a form.  I've tried several ways to get the form selection into a form field but so far no luck. Here is what I consider my best attempt, based on other bootstrap related posts.

```
<form name="formmail" method="post" action="formmail.cgi" onsubmit="return">
    <div class=" form-group ">
        <input type="hidden " name="Flag " id=flagstrap value=" " />
        <label>Select Country</label>
        <br>
        <div class="flagstrap " 
            data-input-name="country " 
            data-button-size="btn-md " 
            data-button-type="btn-default " 
            data-scrollable="true ">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="button " type="submit " value="Send "/>
</form>
<script>
    $('.flagstrap').flagStrap();
    $('.flagstrap').val($(this).text());
</script>
```

You can find flagstrap at https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap

Comment: Try this: `$(".flagstrap").find("select").change(function(){alert($(this).val());});`

Comment: This pops up an alert window with the correct value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Hakerman's comment, I was finally able to figure it out

```
<form name="formmail" method="post" action="formmail.cgi" onsubmit="return">
<div class=" form-group ">
    <input type="hidden " name="Flag " id=flagstrap value=" " />
    <label>Select Country</label>
    <br>
    <div class="flagstrap " 
        data-input-name="country " 
        data-button-size="btn-md " 
        data-button-type="btn-default " 
        data-scrollable="true ">
    </div>
</div>
<input class="button " type="submit " value="Send "/>
</form>
<script>
    $('.flagstrap').flagStrap();
    $(".flagstrap").find("select").change(function(){ $('input[name= Flag]').val($(this).val());})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an extra form field, that plugin creates a `select` element on initialization which will have the value you are looking for. The input has the name declared by you in the `data-input-name` attribute so in this case `"country"`.

If you are using PHP you would access the value with `$_POST['country']`

Comment: I can't use PHP.  I have very limited permissions on this server, I can't even run any other cgi on this server other than formmail